# What does 1 and 0 mean on this power supply?

Tags: power-supply

I have a Shaw Scientific power supply. On the front there is a switch to set the voltage from 0 to 12 volts. There is an on/off switch. There are connections for ac and also for dc. Then there is a switch with two options, 1 and 0. What could this function be ?[image]

Comment: Shaw appears to be a house brand of the Australian company, MSY. You should contact them by phone and ask if someone here doesn't provide a definitive answer. However, the only intuitive idea I have is that it is +0 or +1 to the setting on the left side, which is only ***even*** numbers. So this allows the selection of ***odd numbered*** voltages, if you want them.

Comment: What would be wrong if you try various combinations and measure the result with a voltmeter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to the two dials, they are used to set the voltage - hence the label "Set Voltage".

At a rough guess you select the voltage you want from the sum of the two dials. The left dial gives you even voltages (multiples of two), and then use the right dial to achieve odd numbers.

For example 9V would be selecting the "8" on the left dial, and "1" on the right dial, to give you 8+1=9V. You can select 4V by selecting "4" on the left dial, and "0" on the right dial giving 4+0=4V.

You can confirm or reject this assumption by testing the power supplies.

Comment: That makes sense. I’ll verify the next chance I get.